# How to use animation after shared element transition

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm use shared element transtion go to activity2 and in activity2  the transtion is not working

```
ttb = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.ttb_animation);
slogan = findViewById(R.id.slogan);
slogan.startAnimation(ttb);
```

i try to use delay with handler its work, but i dont need it.

```
Intent goto_activity2 = new Intent(SplashAct.this, Activity2.class);
            ActivityOptionsCompat option = ActivityOptionsCompat
                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SplashAct.this, app_logo, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(app_logo));
            startActivity(goto_activity2, option.toBundle());
            finish();
```

xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="800"
    android:startOffset="100"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    >

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="350"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.2"
        android:fromYScale="1.2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        />

</set>
```

transition in activity2 is not working

Comment: can you provide your xml code plz.As shared element transtition doesnt require any handler.

Comment: oke, check it...

Answer (score 0):

For shared element transition  you need to provide same transtionName to the respective view in both the acitivties. 
In Activity A , suppose youhave a image view

```
 <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/ivImage"
      android:transitionName="transitionName"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="160dp" />
```

and in your activity B :

```
 <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/ivSenderImage"
      android:transitionName="transitionName"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="160dp" />
```

Then while navigating to another activity , all  you hav to do is :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AcitvityA.this, ActivityB.class);
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, (View)ivImage, "transitionName");
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Thats all , with the transition name ensures that even if you have multiple views with the same transition name in the source hierarchy, it will essentially be able to pick the right view to start the animation from.

Or you can check this too https://medium.com/@aitorvs/android-shared-element-transitions-for-all-b90e9361507d . and https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html